# How to customize SOQL date format

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce

When i select the data from salesforce using the SOQL, am getting the date format as 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm' for a date column.

How cam we customize this date value to this format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply arbitrary formatting to date-time results in SOQL. By default, you'll receive the ISO8601 format shown in your question.

You may request a formatted date using the [`FORMAT()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_format.htm) SOQL function. The result is

> When the FORMAT function is applied these fields reflect the appropriate format for the given user locale. The field format matches what appears in the Salesforce Classic user interface. For example, the date December 28, 2015 can appear numerically as 2015-12-28, 28-12-2015, 28/12/2015, 12/28/2015, or 28.12.2015, depending on the org’s locale setting.

You cannot supply a locale or date format to this function. If you need a format other than the user locale, perform this transformation in your client application.